# SQL How to SUM up the total Quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server

1.The customer id, company name, number of orders, and total order amount for all customers who purchased an item in the Beverages category.

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CompanyName, Categories.CategoryName, [Order Details].Quantity
FROM Customers, Categories, [Order Details]
WHERE Categories.CategoryName ='Beverages';
```

Then a new query

2.Same as problem 1 but, limit the list to all customers who placed 3 or more orders. Do I use the =>3 command ?

Comment: its ">=" not "=>"
try adding "AND [Order Details].Quantity >= 3" at the end of your query

Comment: You need to show relations between tables Customers, Categories & [Order Details]. And learn about `GROUPBY` & `HAVING` it could solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the "GROUP BY" and "HAVING" help me out a lot. And letting me know its ">="

Comment: Add some sample data with your expected output from them. This will help.

Comment: **No no no no no** learn to join your tables using the modern join syntax not this ancient and error-prone <from clause> syntax. If you validated your first query, you will realize it is not logically correct.

Answer (score 0):

This question might sound simple, but we need to get the customers who placed more that 3 orders first before joining other tables.

```
select t1.CustomerID
    , t1.CompanyName
    , t3.CategoryName
    , t4. Quantity
from Customers t1
inner join 
    (select customerId from 
    [Order Details]
    where categoryId = (select categoryId from Categories where CategoryName ='Beverages')
    group by customerId
    having count(1) >= 3) t2 on t2.CustomerID = t1.customerId
inner join [Order Details] t4 on t4.CustomerID = t1.customerId
inner join Categories t3 on t3.CategoryId = t4.CategoryId
 where t3.CategoryName ='Beverages'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
SELECT t1.CustomerID
    , t1.CompanyName
    , t3.Categoryname
    , t4. Quantity,noorders
FROM Customers t1
INNER JOIN [Order Details] t4 ON t4.CustomerID = t1.customerId
INNER JOIN Categories t3 ON t3.CategoryId = t4.CategoryId
CROSS APPLY (SELECT noorders=count(orderid) FROM [Order Details] ord2 
        WHERE ord2.CustomerID=t4.CustomerID and ord2.CategoryId = t3.CategoryId) AS t2
 WHERE t3.CategoryName ='Beverages'
 and t2.noorders>=3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what final work for me

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CompanyName, Categories.CategoryName,
Sum([Order Details].Quantity) as TotalOrders, Count (Orders.OrderID)
FROM Customers, Categories, [Order Details], Orders
WHERE Categories.CategoryName ='Beverages'
group by [Order Details].Quantity, Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CompanyName, Categories.CategoryName
Having Count (Orders.OrderID) >=3;
```

Thank you all for the help.